# Predefined picklist value in action layout editor

Tags: lightning, quickaction

I'm trying to create a quick action that works as an action layout editor with predefined values. One of the fields I can't fill is picklist type and when I try setting his value with another picklist for his related object (with same picklist values in both of them) it displays me this error:

**Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions**

I tried using `TEXT(my_custom_field__c)` but it keeps on giving me same message.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this or if it's just a salesforce limitation for now?

Answer (score 2):

This is a limitation with salesforce. [Actions: Predefined picklists can be set by formula](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Df0HAAS) idea is under product team review in ideaexchange. You can only set specific value with lookup as of now.

Or, you can have a `CASE` formula to predefine picklist value. [*But I am not sure if formula character limit exceed if you have number of values*]
Like this

```
CASE(my_custom_field__c, 
"Prospecting", "prospecting",
"Qualification", "qualification",
"Needs Analysis", "needs analysis",
"Value Proposition", "value proposition",
---------
"")
```

Comment: I saw the 'CASE' solution but we have 234 values on that picklist field so this is not an option, but thanks for the quick response and related url link.